# MVC-3 Doesn't Find Pre-compiled Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, view, razorgenerator

I have a common MVC3 project which has some views which are compiled into the assembly using RazorGenerator. I've confirmed that the classes show up in the resulting DLL. I've referenced this project from another MVC3 project. When I try to use a view in the common MVC project (the view's namespace is `CommonMvcProject.Views.Shared`, for instance)...

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("ViewFromCommonMVCProject");}
```

...I get an error:

> The partial view 'ViewFromCommonMVCProject' was not found or no view engine
>   supports the searched locations.

I don't want to use the physical views, I want to use the pre-compiled views in the common MVC project's assembly. How can I configure this project to search within the common assembly?

Answer (score 0):

The following post looks like it has the details you need.

http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/

Hope that helps.